# Merging two float dataframes into one string dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

So let's say I have two dataframe, where one contains the nominal values and the other contains uncertainties to the nominal values:

```
import pandas as pd

df_nom = pd.DataFrame([1.5, 2.5], 
                      [3.5, 4.5])

df_err = pd.DataFrame([5.1, 6.1], 
                      [7.1, 8.1])
```

I'd like to merge the two to become string dataframe as such:

```
df_merged = pd.DataFrame(['1.5 $\pm$ 5.1', '2.5 $\pm$ 6.1'],
                         ['3.5 $\pm$ 7.1', '4.5 $\pm$ 8.1'])
```

Can anybody help me with this? Preferably in a vectorize and efficient way.
I am also open if there is a smarter way of doing this than converting them to strings.
What I want in the end is to output the dataframe as latex table using DataFrame.to_latex()

Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
df = df_nom.astype(str) + ' $\pm$ ' + df_err.astype(str)
print (df)
               0              1
0  1.5 $\pm$ 5.1  2.5 $\pm$ 6.1
1  3.5 $\pm$ 7.1  4.5 $\pm$ 8.1
```